# My android app work in version 8 (Oreo) but not work in version 4.4 (KitKat)

Tags: android

I have a problem when I run my app in android version 8; The following error shows in the log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mirasoft.mirasoftaccounting, PID: 2734
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.R$attr
        at uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyConfig$Builder.<init>(CalligraphyConfig.java:194)
        at com.mirasoft.mirasoftaccounting.public_package.MyApplication.updateLanguage(MyApplication.java:80)
        at com.mirasoft.mirasoftaccounting.public_package.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:48)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: check the following issues on the library you're using: https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy/issues?q=NoClassDefFoundError%3A+uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.R%24attr. it seems like a multidex issue. make sure you're setting up your multidex properly and before initialising Calligraphy.

Comment: how i can setting up multidex properly

Comment: check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex#mdex-pre-l